# How do i replace my branch content with master?

Tags: git, github, version-control, git-bash

I have a `master` branch with my original file  **A.txt**.
Now I created a branch: `git checkout -b MyBranch` (This is where now I make my changes).

Now, I have modified the contents of **A.txt** and ran  `git add -u`. Even though I do not need these changes, I proceed ahead and perform  `git commit -m "changes to A.txt"` followed by `git push`.

Now i do not wish to `merge` these changes with my `master`, rather I wish to get the original content from the `master` to `MyBranch`.

How do I perform this? Could someone please guide me here?

Comment: There are a few options: you can merge `master` into `MyBranch`; you can rebase `MyBranch` on top of `master`, or you can cherrypick new commits from `master` into `MyBranch` (which is kind of like a partial merge). Which you choose depends on why you have a separate branch in the first place.

Comment: @chepner Will it undo the current changes I pushed on `MyBranch`?

Comment: That depends on what "original content" you are talking about. Other files? They won't affect `A.txt`. If there are *other* changes in `master`'s copy of `A.txt`, you might have a merge conflict that you'll have to resolve yourself, but it shouldn't automatically undo your `MyBranch` changes.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

I think @chepner has provided a very apt answer. Although I am still  confused with what you want.

> Now, I have modified the contents of A.txt and ran git add -u. Even though I do not need these changes, I proceed ahead and perform git commit -m "changes to A.txt" followed by git push.

At this point, you have an editied version of `A.txt` in `MyBranch`. If you are actually trying to add your changes to the index then I think the `-u` option isn't a good choice. The aforementioned does not add any new changes to the index. Hence, committing changes at this point is of no use.

Anyway, *assuming* you made a commit in the `MyBranch`, if you don't want to merge these changes to `master`, then leave this branch as-is, *i.e.*, switch to `master` by: `git checkout master`.

If you want to get the original content from `master`, then I think when you checked out to `MyBranch`, you would have gotten them already, but I *think* you might mean that you want to revert this commit to get to the same state as `master` in `MyBranch`. In that case, you can drop the new commit you made, either by `git rebase` or you can do a `git reset --hard @~1`. The `@~1` means that you want to go to 1 commit before the current HEAD *i.e.*, the commit you just made.

Best.

Comment: As suggested by you in the last paragraph, I want MyBranch to be in same state as my master. In order to do so i have to run `git rebase` or `git reset --hard @~1` right? I will try the same, i hope this is what i am looking for.

Thank You.